# gettting child tree from main tree php

Tags: php, tree, treeview

i have created a tree from flat php array now i want to get the child tree from the main tree, i want to pass the child id and get the child item's tree

```
$flat = [
    ['id' => 100, 'parent_id' => 0, 'name' => 'root'],
    ['id' => 101, 'parent_id' => 100, 'name' => 'ch-1'],
    ['id' => 102, 'parent_id' => 101, 'name' => 'ch-1-1'],
    ['id' => 103, 'parent_id' => 101, 'name' => 'ch-1-2'],
    ['id' => 104, 'parent_id' => 101, 'name' => 'ch-1-2'],
    ['id' => 105, 'parent_id' => 104, 'name' => 'ch-1-2'],
    ['id' => 106, 'parent_id' => 101, 'name' => 'ch-1-2'],
    ['id' => 107, 'parent_id' => 101, 'name' => 'ch-1-2'],
];

$tree = getchildtree($flat, '101');
print_r($tree);
```

Comment: i can create tree from whole array, but not able to get specific child tree

Comment: Show desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

$flat = [
    ['id' => 100, 'parent_id' => 0, 'name' => 'root'],
    ['id' => 101, 'parent_id' => 100, 'name' => 'ch-1'],
    ['id' => 102, 'parent_id' => 101, 'name' => 'ch-1-1'],
    ['id' => 103, 'parent_id' => 101, 'name' => 'ch-1-2'],
    ['id' => 104, 'parent_id' => 101, 'name' => 'ch-1-2'],
    ['id' => 105, 'parent_id' => 104, 'name' => 'ch-1-2'],
    ['id' => 106, 'parent_id' => 101, 'name' => 'ch-1-2'],
    ['id' => 107, 'parent_id' => 101, 'name' => 'ch-1-2'],
];

$index = array_search($user_id, array_column($data, 'id'));
$new = array();
foreach ($flat as $a){
    $new[$a['parent_id']][] = $a;
}
$tree = createTree($new, array($data[$index]));
print_r($tree);

function createTree(&$list, $parent){
    $tree = array();
    foreach ($parent as $k=>$l){
        if(isset($list[$l['id']])){
            $l['children'] = createTree($list, $list[$l['id']]);
        }
        $tree[] = $l;
    } 
    return $tree;
}
```

[check demo](https://3v4l.org/qIJrl)

Comment: This is converting the whole array into tree, i need to get any specific tree from the whole tree

Comment: Thank You soo much, i merge both answers and get my result .

Comment: You can edit my answer So that in future it'll help to others.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$flat = [
    ['id' => 100, 'parent_id' => 0, 'name' => 'root'],
    ['id' => 101, 'parent_id' => 100, 'name' => 'ch-1'],
    ['id' => 102, 'parent_id' => 101, 'name' => 'ch-1-1'],
    ['id' => 103, 'parent_id' => 101, 'name' => 'ch-1-2'],
    ['id' => 104, 'parent_id' => 101, 'name' => 'ch-1-2'],
    ['id' => 105, 'parent_id' => 104, 'name' => 'ch-1-2'],
    ['id' => 106, 'parent_id' => 101, 'name' => 'ch-1-2'],
    ['id' => 107, 'parent_id' => 101, 'name' => 'ch-1-2'],
];

$index = array_search(101, array_column($flat, 'parent_id'));

var_dump($flat[$index]);

?>
```

A thought:

Since you're building the array yourself, why don't you consider a structure something similar to

```
$flat[$parent_id][] = [
   'id' => $child_id,
   'name' => $child_name
];
```

Then you can get the child tree(s) from the main tree as follows

```
$child_tree = $flat[$parent_id];
```

Comment: Thanks it help me to find the index of ID and use the index to draw my tree using the answer below.